# Custom style a particular road using CartoCSS/TileMill/OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, cartocss

For a particular city, I want to make the label for its main street labeled as prominently as Motorways. i.e. although this road would normally only be labeled from about zoom level 15 and up, I would like it to be visibly labeled from zoom level 12.

Is there a syntax I can use in TileMill's CartoCSS to allow me to custom adjust label properties for this particular road? Ideally it could be based on road name (e.g. "Mary Street") but pretty much any solution could work such as using its ID number, because we only have to do it once.

Comment: Alternatively you could do some pre-processing and change the *tags* of the road in question. For example invent a new value for the *highway* key, apply it to the road and add it to your stylesheet.

Comment: Why not using Maperitive an Dataextract and an adapted map style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the attribute data with `[name='Mary Street']`.
[Please look at my CartoCSS answer here. "Orchard Road" was used as more information was provided in the comments.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110407/tilemill-multiple-design-feature-of-the-label-road/110513#110513)  Depending on what other road types were involved, one test had to use `[name!='Mary Street']` for styling purposes.